# Hide "moderator recalcs rep" entries from the user history by default

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, reputation-recalc

Moderators have access to a history of events for every user account. This contains fairly important stuff like suspension, moderator messages and annotations, but also some stuff that moderators almost never need to know.

The biggest offender in terms of noise is the "moderator recalcs rep" message which in the case of a well-behaved user often makes up at least 90% of all messages in their history. I'm not exactly sure when it happens, but it is triggered very regularly whenever the user's reputation is adjusted automatically by the system. It is of no use to a moderator.

This is how a typical history from a well-behaved and very active user looks:

[image]

The exception would be events that indicate that serial voting was reversed or votes invalidated by SE, but I'm not sure how exactly those appear in the history and if they are a different event type. Those should still appear in the history.

But the automatic rep recalcs should go, they only add noise.

Comment: Well, there is the 'change filter', but I agree that the way it's displayed in general isn't optimal. Rather than hide certain things by default, it might be better to just examine how it could be displayed better overall.

Comment: @TimPost Change filter only allows to view one category of events at a time. Just hiding the noise events would be sufficient, most accounts don't have much activity in the other categories. The default view should only show events that are actually important, and hide all others.

Comment: "Moderators have access to a history of events for every user account" - Does this include votes?

Comment: @MikeB No, it does not

Comment: Any chance we can get a "SELECT DISTINCT action FROM user_actions" ?