# Can the links in the "possible vandalism: edits" flag point to the revision rather than the post

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools

When we get the following flag:

> possible vandalism: edits (auto)

We see a set of links to the **posts** that have been edited.

This means that to check that edit is valid we have to click the link to the post then click the link to the revisions on that post and then go back twice to get back to the flag to check the other posts.

It would be far more efficient if the links were to the **revisions** page rather than the post itself. It would make checking these flag much quicker.

Comment: I've added a link to this from the [How can we improve the mod tools?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189515/how-can-we-improve-the-mod-tools) question.

Comment: I was just about to re-ask this. It is without a doubt the first thing I always do when going through these flags and it amplifies the tedious bits of reviewing them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Oded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/140505/oded) was kind enough to complete this in the latest build.  When this flag is generated you will now have links to the revision page of the answer, instead of only to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

While I agree that this is theoretically a good idea, it unfortunately doesn't really justify the amount of time it would take to implement. We discussed this, and it only affects something like 800 posts in the history of Stack Exchange, so we'd rather focus our efforts on things that have a bigger impact.

Comment: I'm not disputing your figures, but I surprised that there have only been 800 "possible vandalism (edits)" flags.

Comment: 876 moderator-handled flags of that type, 904 in total. Contrast with the deletion vandalism flag, which has over 5K in its history.

Comment: How do these counts compare to anon edits in the review queue that were rejected with the vandalism reason, but didn't raise an autoflag?