# Can the linked posts in a "possible vandalism edits" flag go directly to the edit, instead of the post?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools

When handling automatically-raised flags for "possible vandalism edits", the links to the edited posts go to the post itself, instead of the edit. Linking directly to the post isn't useful; in every case I need to click the "edited  minutes ago" link to see what the edit introduced/removed.

Can these links go directly to `/<post_id>/revisions/<revision_id>` and show me the edit the contributed towards the flag being raised?

---

While there is a [previous status-declined duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190303/can-the-links-in-the-possible-vandalism-edits-flag-point-to-the-revision-rath), @bluefeet asked me to leave this intact for future reconsideration.

Comment: Voted to leave open for now, but it might be better to just rip the [status-declined] off the old post and reconsider it.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist I didn't ask for a dup proposal to be posted. This was posted and then we found out it was a dup. meagar asked me if it should be deleted, I said to leave this instead of deleting so it could still point to the duplicate version.  I'm not removing the `status-declined` on the other one yet as I need to look into the possibility of doing this.